# Dropdown Customization to hide & unhide

Tags: excel, vba

- I already have dropdown in place where it shows different Departments names, eg: PM, SCM, including **NONE** etc.

*My expectation:*

I want the code to run in such a manner that when I select PM, it should only display PM. When I select PM and SCM, both of them are to be seen and the other departments should be hidden.

When I select **NONE** for that cell, that particular department should be hidden and others, if any should be still seen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where do you have the dropdown? are there 3 like in the picture? where is the data which should be hidden or not, is this the 2nd picture? Do you have any code? Which Excel Version do you use.

Comment: 1,2,3 are the dropdown, which is in the sheet 1 and 2nd picture is sheet2 in which data should be hidden. My excel version is 2010. I tried with one code but with that code i can hide only one department. @Chris Should I upload that code? It is the simple code for hiding one department.

Comment: You have 3 Dropdowns. So you can choose max. 3 departments which should not be hidden. Also you can choose None. For example you choose: None+PM+SCM, what should happen? Is there a difference to choose PM+None+SCM or PM+SCM+None. Whats happen if you choose None+None+None?

Comment: Yes 3 departments should not be hidden. There is no difference if you choose none anywhere. For eg: None + None +None = all departments should be hidden. If None + PM + SCM then just PM and SCM should be shown.  basically NONE should be nothing . NONE is because there should be option for just showing One department.

Comment: I have uploaded answer for above code. Just change Range according to your needs. i need to implement offset when this value matches it should unhide above 3 rows too. i am not sure where to use offset `Range(Selection.Offset(-3), Cells(RowCnt, 1)).Rows.Hidden = False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for my query

```
Sub Hide2ndFix()
'
' Hide2ndFix Macro
'
Dim RowCnt As Long, uRng As Range
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3 As String

Dim s As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

BeginRow = 2
EndRow = 20
ChkCol = 1
Set s = Range("A2:A20")

With s
.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End With

str1 = Range("C3").Value

str2 = Range("C4").Value

str3 = Range("C5").Value

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = str1 Or Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = str2 Or Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = str3 Then
         If uRng Is Nothing Then
          Set uRng = Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol)

         Else
          Set uRng = Union(uRng, Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol))

         End If

        End If
    Next RowCnt

 If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Where can i add offset and unhide above three rows. i tried using this `Range(Selection.Offset(-3), Cells(RowCnt, 1)).Rows.Hidden = False`. not sure where to use so while str matches it should unhide above three rows too.

Comment: for eg : If department is PPE then it should show PPE (Row 9) and show above 3 rows also(6,7,8).